# Unable to notify ad delegate about native ad being loaded: NSLayoutConstraint for <MANativeAdView:

Tags: ios, objective-c, ads, applovin

I am trying to show the native ads in my iOS app. I have a list in my home screen. So trying to add the ads inbetweeen the list of my app.

But while trying to load the ads, I am getting the below error.

Error:

> [AppLovinSdk] ERROR [ALDelegateCallbackInvoker] Unable to notify ad
> delegate about native ad being loaded: NSLayoutConstraint for
> <MANativeAdView: 0x7f9490d1e5a0; frame = (0 0; 300 250); clipsToBounds
> = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000017ee440>>: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with
> a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a
> location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in
> pairs.

Code:

```
 if ( self.loadedNativeAd )
    {
        [self.nativeAdLoader destroyAd: self.loadedNativeAd];
    }

        // Save ad for cleanup.
        self.loadedNativeAd = ad;
    
    // Save ad for cleanup
       self.nativeAd = ad;
       
       // Add ad view to view
       self.nativeAdView = nativeAdView;
       [self.nativeAdContainerView addSubview: nativeAdView];
        
       
       // Set to false if modifying constraints after adding the ad view to your layout
       self.nativeAdContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       // [self.nativeAdLoader loadAdIntoAdView: [self createNativeAdView]];
       
       // Set ad view to span width and height of container and center the ad
    [self.nativeAdContainerView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: nativeAdView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.nativeAdContainerView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier: 1 constant: 0]];
    [self.nativeAdContainerView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: nativeAdView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.nativeAdContainerView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier: 1 constant: 0]];
    [self.nativeAdContainerView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: nativeAdView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.nativeAdContainerView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier: 1 constant: 0]];
    [self.nativeAdContainerView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: nativeAdView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.nativeAdContainerView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier: 1 constant: 0]];
```